# How to close an NSWindow during UI Testing with Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode-ui-testing

I am developing a document based Application for macOS. How can I close an existing NSWindow at the beginning of a test case?

Answer (score 0):

This was the code that does the trick. I had problems not saving it. Not sure why, but then I realised that there might be cases when I want to save the existing document anyway.

```
 var untitledWindow = app.windows["Untitled"]
    if untitledWindow.exists {
        untitledWindow.typeKey("w", modifierFlags:.command)
        //untitledWindow.buttons[XCUIIdentifierCloseWindow].click() should work too
        if untitledWindow.buttons["Save"].exists{
            untitledWindow.buttons["Save"].click()
        }
        if untitledWindow.buttons["Replace"].exists {
            untitledWindow.buttons["Replace"].click()
        }
    }
```